# VP Definition: Why polynomial bound on the degree?

Tags: computational-complexity

The complexity class $\mathbf{VP}$ (Valiant P) is defined to be the class of all polynomials of *polynomially bounded degree* which can be realized by an arithmetic circuit family with polynomially bounded size.

My questions are:

1. Why do we require the degree to be polynomially bounded?
2. Which complexity class to we get if we omit this constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It rules out sequences like $p_n=X^{2^n}$, which can be computed by a straight-line program using $n$ multiplications, but on a Turing machine these multiplications would take exponentially long. However, VP does allow things like $p_n=X+2^{2^n}$, which is still weird from the Turing machine point of view.
2. A bigger class, called $VP_{nb}$ in *[Interpolation in Valiant's theory](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/pascal.koiran/Publis/interpolation.pdf)* (where it is attributed to a 2003 PhD thesis by Guillaume Malod).